# Cannot convert objects to strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, console

[image: Console image]

I have this in my console. 
It is a model object that is called in my code "this.model" but when I do a

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model.attributes));
```

in my code, I get

```
{"language":"en","trans":"","lang":"en"}
```

It is not converting my array of objects to a string.

Why is trans an empty string?

The jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Te5RH/ but I'm not sure how to add the json file in the jsfiddle but it looks like:

```
{
 "app": {
    "name": "Contest"
 },
 "nav": {
    "home": "Home",
    "page1": "Page One",
    "page2": "Page Two"
 }
}
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a fiddle demo that you can show?

Comment: What the original object is? just to test... you know

Comment: I've added the jsfiddle url.

Answer (score 0):

To me you have a timing issue. There are good chances that when you issue the console.log the object is not filled. Something like this:

```
var x = {'a':3, trans:"",'c':null};
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
x.trans = {app:{name:'Contest'}, nav:[2,'alpha']};
```

In the inspector you will see the "full version" of the object but at the time of the console log the object is not *"ready"*.

Answer (score -2):

That's because `trans` is not a `string` property, it seems that `JSON.stringify` can't iterate `Object` properties of your object.

Look at that function.